# can't run new android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just created a new project on Android and it shows the following:

[image]

I am not sure why this is, I didn't even touch the code and I don't see any error anywhere.
Why is this?

Comment: What's in the "Problems" tab?

Comment: Did you look in the Problems tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Problems tab at the bottom of your picture. Click the left-arrow next to 'Errors' and it will list the problems.